# Associate image to a row on database php

Tags: php, image

So, I have a folder with images, each image having a number that corresponds to a "productid" on my database. How can I show the images, each one corresponding to the correct id? I'm working with php at the moment.

```
<?php 

require('connection.php');

 $type=$conn->prepare('SELECT ProdutoTipo FROM produtos');
$id=$conn->prepare('SELECT ProdutoID FROM produtos');

?>

    <?php
function addZero($number){
    switch(strlen((string)$number)){
        case 1: return '00'.$number;
            break;
        case 2: return '0'.$number;
            break;
        case 3: return $number;
            break;
        default: return $number;
            break;
    }
}

function getImage($type, $id){

    require('connection.php');
    //$imageList = array(scandir('./images/components/'.$type.'/'));
    $imageList = array_diff(scandir('Imagens/'.$type) array('..', '.'));
    //var_dump($imageList);
    if(in_array(addZero($id).'.jpg', $imageList, true)){
        echo addZero($id) . '.jpg';
    } elseif(in_array(addZero($id).'.png', $imageList, true)){
        echo addZero($id) . '.png';
    } elseif(in_array(addZero($id).'.jpeg', $imageList, true)) {
        echo addZero($id) . '.jpeg';
    } else{
        echo '9999.jpg';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Post the PHP code you are working with at the moment to make the necessary changes. Click "edit" below your question and paste the code.

Comment: I know this all messy, but if you could help me I would really apreciate

Comment: I think we are all here to learn. If you could help instead of making negative comments I would really apreciate.

Comment: Why are you doing 2 queries right off the bat when 1 query will do?

Comment: @Chino. Correct, but some are here **just to get their work done for them**

Comment: This code is **nothing to do** with the process you are asking about. So I guess I got you pegged

Comment: Are you using `PDO` or `MYSQLI_`

Comment: I'm using PDO right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your image folder is stored in YOUR_PATH and image filenames are something like image_{product_id}.jpg you can first get all the product ids from the db then loop through them like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php foreach($product_id_list as $product_id){ ?>
       <img src="YOUR_PATH/image_<?php echo $product_id ?>.jpg" />
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok I've got it working riccardo thanks for your help!  and I'm sorry for not being that explicit. Just started programming :)